# Source of Referral in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

request.referre or request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] giving me current URL but I want to fetch the Facebook/linkedin URL where my event published. Please help me i am new in rails

```
if @request=request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
  # request.env['HTTP_REFERER'].include?('facebook')
      ExternalRefer.create(:name =>request.env['HTTP_REFERER'], :ip => client_ip.to_s )
end
```

Comment: You should add some more info about what is happening here, eg how it's published to facebook, and where does the request you talk about fit into that?

Comment: Yes, it published on facebook page on my profile.

Comment: Actually problem is getting the current URL rather then referral URL.

Comment: If I get the idea, you want something like this: when somebody clicks on a link to your Rails application, you would like to record the site where the link is placed. Is this correct?